# Heroku Edge Addon Amazon Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

My app's `slugsize` exceeded the Heroku max limit so I added the Heroku Edge Addon to my application in an effort to move the largest size folder, which is `public/img`, to a CDN (Amazon Cloudfront). I do not have an AWS account.

I added the CDN `EDGE_URL` provided by the addon to the`<img src=>` tags on my website. Works fine so far.

My question is where do I manage the Cloudfront portion of things since there is no dashboard on Heroku. Do I need to sign up for an AWS account? What files/folders do I include in the `.slugignore` file? Do I need to manually move the `public/img` folder to Cloudfront? I use Github for version control and I typically push to Heroku for deployment. Do I need to `rm` the `public/img` folder from Github and add it to my `.gitignore` file moving forward?